# Count Course Inside An Array

Tags: java, arrays, count

Good Evening,

I'm trying to figure out if its possible to count inside an array certain courses. Here's my example below.

Example:

```
list.add(new Student(" Bourne", "70","\tCOP2250, ENC3250, COP3530"));
list.add(new Student(" Gracia", "50","\tCOP2250, COP3250, COP4250"));


Output:

COP2250 - 2
COP3530 - 1
ENC3250 - 1
```

The output should be like above. Let me know if its possible to do this or I would need to sort courses alone.

Thanks in advance for any support.

Comment: It is very much possible. There are quite a few ways to do this... I don't remember much java, but in C++ TL:DR; you could create a vector of pairs. Each pair would be a string name of the course, and a count value. Then loop the courses, loop through the vector to see if its pair exists, if so add 1 to the count, if not create a pair and push_back to the vector. At the very end you can loop the vector, which will have a count for each unique course. That is pretty confusing and probably way simpler in Java, like what @user7790438 suggested.

Comment: do you have a list of all possible courses?

Comment: try this int count = Collections.frequency(Arrays.asList(array), your_stufrn_with_your_course);

Comment: @Hannes My list is the shown above. Everything is stored in
    List<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
Map<String, Integer> cources = new HashMap<>();
for (Student s : list) {
    //I assumed that eg. "\tCOP2250, ENC3250, COP3530" is in a (public) variable Cources 
    //in your Student class. You can replace this by a getter or whatever you need.
    for (String name : s.Courses.replace("\t", "").split(", ")) {
        if (cources.containsKey(name))
            cources.replace(name, cources.get(name)+1);
        else
            cources.put(name, 1);
    }
}
//some output for testing
cources.forEach((a, b) -> System.out.println(a + " - " + b));
```

Comment: That was it! Dude, you're a life saver. I had an idea about using HashMap but did not even know where to start. Thank you very much, have a great night!